# Sending data from form python

Tags: python, django, forms

When I click on `search` button I need to get data using google api, but I get this error page. 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/imj6T.png

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="some text"><br>
        <button class="button" name="submit" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'index.html', context={})

    # Handles the search once the submit button in the form is pressed
    # which sends a "POST" request
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Get the input data from the POST request
        search_query = request.POST.get('search', None)

        # Validate input data
        if search_query and search_query != "":
            try: 
                from googlesearch import search 
            except ImportError:  
                print("No module named 'google' found")

            for j in search(search_query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
                print(j)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid input.')
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='home')
]
```

Please, help to solve that.

Comment: i tagged it with _dajngo_ ;)

Answer (score 0):

When there is a POST request, you only return something on failure, you may add a return-Statement at every possible ending of the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
if search_query and search_query != "":
            try: 
                from googlesearch import search 
            except ImportError:  
                print("No module named 'google' found")

            for j in search(search_query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=1, pause=2): 
                print(j)
```

In this part of the code you need to response something